# Shouldn't the tag "quotes" be "comments" or "strings"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just came across tags [quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quotes) and [quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quoting):
Surprisingly [quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quotes) seems to describe what I would call "comments" or strings. The tag excerpt is:

> Computer programming languages' facility for embedding text in source code, also known as String literals

and the tag description:

> In plain English: String literals can be enclosed in matching single
> quotes (') or double quotes (").
>
> ### References:
>
> - [JavaScript Strings](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)
> - [Python docs. String literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)
> - [Javs docs. String literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

while the second one actually refers to what I'd call "quotes". The tag excerpt is:

> The use of quotation marks (typically, `'` or `"`) to mark tokens as string literals or strings subject to interpolation, or to treat multiple whitespace-separated tokens as a single unit.

and the tag description is:

> Use this tag for questions about the correct use of quotation marks in programming, with respect to:
>
> - how to use quotation marks to mark text as a literal not to be interpreted in any way.
> - how to use quotation marks to mark text as subject to [string interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation).
> - how to escape (encode) quotation marks inside text already enclosed in quotation marks.
>
> Especially in shell programming, with respect to:
>
> - when what quotation marks are needed, and if quoting is needed at all, including quoting of individual characters with `\`.
> - how to use quoting to partition a list of tokens into distinct arguments that may have embedded whitespace.
> - when quotation marks are considered part of the input vs. recognized syntactically by the shell (quote removal).

Is the existence of tag [quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quotes) as it is now justified?

Comment: Seems to me like you're 100% right, but I would wait for whoever setup these tags to argue their side.

Comment: comment <> string

Comment: *"Is the existence of tag quotes as it is now justified?"* it is just as justified as filling up all five tag slots under a question. It isn't, but social media sites have conditioned people to do it.

Comment: I think that the name is misleading; maybe `use-of-quotes` would be a better name, as it wouldn't be as generic as `quotes` is; if it really does not mean `string-syntax` or `comment-syntax` (as opposed to `quoting-semantics`). -- I tried to emphasize my points using tag names that may not exist at all...